# How to Integration Stripe Payment gateway in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I followed [this link](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-stripe-into-laravel-4-application/).

I did what it said, but its throwing some error:

> FatalErrorException in routes.php line 29:
>   Class 'Stripe' not found
>   Line 29 Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_bDgMM85Y8hWWaRRBrulWNeng');

Comment: Did you install stripe via composer ?

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check...

1. Did you install your stripe dependency? `composer require stripe/stripe-php`
2. Did you `composer dump-auto`
3. Your tutorial link runs stripe from the Routes file. Which is in the global namespace. Are you executing this code from a Controller or from the routes file? If from a controller, then you will need to add a use statement at the top `use Stripe\Stripe;`
4. Finally, which version of the https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php package are you using? According to the readme, there is a legacy version and a new version. The new version is has an extra level of nesting and is accessed via `Stripe\Stripe` and `Stripe\Charge`:

Legacy Version

```
Stripe::setApiKey('d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249');
$myCard = array('number' => '4242424242424242', 'exp_month' => 8, 'exp_year' => 2018);
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array('card' => $myCard, 'amount' => 2000, 'currency' => 'usd'));
echo $charge;
```

New Version

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249');
$myCard = array('number' => '4242424242424242', 'exp_month' => 8, 'exp_year' => 2018);
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array('card' => $myCard, 'amount' => 2000, 'currency' => 'usd'));
echo $charge;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the thing I did and its working. Hope its work is case of your:

```
  try {
        Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
          'name' => 'Jenny Rosen',
          'email' => 'jenyy@hotmail.co.us',
          'address' => [
            'line1' => '510 Townsend St',
            'postal_code' => '98140',
            'city' => 'San Francisco',
            'state' => 'CA',
            'country' => 'US',
          ],
        ]);

        \Stripe\Customer::createSource(
          $customer->id,
          ['source' => $request->stripeToken]
        );

        Stripe\Charge::create ([
                "customer" => $customer->id,
                "amount" => 100 * 100,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "description" => "Test payment from stripe.test." , 
        ]);

        Session::flash('success', 'Payment successful!');   

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage().' error occured';
            Session::flash('error','Payment Failed.');
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

***Charge Card***

**First of All create your stripe account**

[Stripe Register Page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/register)

`if you already have Stripe account good to Go`

`Get API key from your Stripe and Add it to your project .env`

**Test API Key link :** https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys

**Live API Key link :** https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys

**NOTE :**  `You can use API key directly in code but it is not good for security` Install stripe-php via composer`

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php `
```

**IF YOU ARE USING IN API**

`Setup client and API In code`

```
Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
```

`Create token for Payment`

```
$token = $stripe->tokens->create([
    'card' => [
    'number'    => $card_number,
    'exp_month' => $exp_month,
    'exp_year'  => $exp_year,
    'cvc'       => $cvc,
    ],
]);
```

`Create Charge`

```
$charge = Stripe\Charge::create ([
    "amount"        => $request->amount *100,
    "currency"      => $request->currency,
    "source"        => $token->id,
    "description"   => 'payment with credit/debit card'
]);
```

**SECURITY RISK:**
`We should create token in front-end instead of sending card details on network we should send token`

**Add JS stripe to your blade file**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

**Creating token On front-end using javaScript**

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
Stripe.createToken({
number: $('.card-number').val(),
cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()

}, stripeResponseHandler);
```

**About stripeResponseHandler**

`This response handler will be a function where Stripe will redirect  after success or failure of creating token`

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

    if (response.error) {
        /* token failed to create  */
    } else {
        var token = response['id'];
        /* you can send this token to back-end [Laravel Controller] then you need to charge function on backed */
    }

}
```

**Hope it will helpful for you**